# I am scraping a site using selenium ,beautifulsoup. Need total no. of pages in website or other way to navigate pages

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am using selenium webdriver and beautiful soup to scrape a website which has a variable number of multiple pages. I am doing it crudely through `xpath`. A page shows five pages and after count is five I press the next button and reset the `xpath` count to get next 5 pages. For this I need total pages in the website through the code or a better way of navigating to different pages.

I think the page uses angular java script for navigation. The code is the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
spg_index=' '
url = "https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/ann.html"
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
html=soup.prettify()
with open('bseann.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(html)
time.sleep(1)
i=1  #index for page numbers navigated. ket at maximum 31 at present
k=1  #goes upto 5, the maximum navigating pages shown at one time
while i <31:
    next_pg=9   #xpath number to pinpoint to "next" page 
    snext_pg=str(next_pg)
    snext_pg=snext_pg.strip()
    if i> 5:
        next_pg=10  #when we go to next set of pages thr is a addl option
        if(i==6) or(i==11)or(i==16):#resetting xpath indx for set of pg's
        k=2
        path='/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li['
        path=path+snext_pg+']/a'
        next_page_btn_list=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(path)
        next_page_btn=next_page_btn_list[0]
        next_page_btn.click()  #click next page
        time.sleep(1)
    pg_index= k+2
    spg_index=str(pg_index)
    spg_index=spg_index.strip()     
    path= '/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li['
    path=path+spg_index+']/a'
    next_page_btn_list=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(path)
    next_page_btn=next_page_btn_list[0]
    next_page_btn.click()  #click specific pg no. 
    time.sleep(1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    html=soup.prettify()
    i=i+1
    k=k+1
    with open('bseann.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(html)
```

Comment: what exaclty are you trying to collect? You can access all the article data via the API which I can provide as a solution, but just need to know what you exactly are looking as your output

Answer (score 1):

No need to use Selenium here as you can access the info from the API. This pulled 247 announcements:

```
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = 'https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/AnnGetData/w'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
'strCat': '-1',
'strPrevDate': '20190423',
'strScrip': '',
'strSearch': 'P',
'strToDate': '20190423',
'strType': 'C'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

df = json_normalize(jsonData['Table'])
df['ATTACHMENTNAME'] = '=HYPERLINK("https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachLive/' + df['ATTACHMENTNAME'] + '")'


df.to_csv('C:/filename.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
...

GYSCOAL ALLOYS LTD. - 533275 - Announcement under Regulation 30 (LODR)-Code of Conduct under SEBI (PIT) Regulations, 2015
https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachLive/82f18673-de98-4a88-bbea-7d8499f25009.pdf

INDIAN SUCROSE LTD. - 500319 - Certificate Under Regulation 40(9) Of Listing Regulation For The Half Year Ended 31.03.2019
https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachLive/2539d209-50f6-4e56-a123-8562067d896e.pdf

Dhanvarsha Finvest Ltd - 540268 - Reply To Clarification Sought From The Company
https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachLive/f8d80466-af58-4336-b251-a9232db597cf.pdf

Prabhat Telecoms (India) Ltd - 540027 - Signing Of Framework Supply Agreement With METRO Cash & Carry India Private Limited
https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachLive/acfb1f72-efd3-4515-a583-2616d2942e78.pdf

...
```

Comment: This is  the right way. Had heard of API for bse data but lacked details & proficiency in how to use it. Thanks a lot.  Not closing the  issue as I may be having some more related questions in this respect. I want  write these announcements a file (may be csv) where I can click the pdf link directly for announcements which I want to see.

Comment: Ok. I’ll add that on in the morning tomorrow. So write to csv. What sort of data are you wanting in the columns? The pdf link, headline, date, etc?

Comment: based on your code, Iam able to write to csv file. I want to write data like date, time, announcement, type of announcement so that it can be segregated, pdf link.  Intend to run a filter before I write data to a file, which can come from text file. Aim to filter  announcements that contain common words like 'Loss of certificate', "Share holding" so as to scan less companies.  Iam looking for a way to 1) get missing data like date,time, type 2) remove commas, special chars from text as it leads to false breakup in csv file.  2) The pdf link does not appear as clickable link in pdf

Comment: @Ravi, ok I’ll look at it again in the morning. What do you mean “pdf link does not appear as clickable link in pdf”?

Comment: when I open the csv file in excel, the pdf link appears in a separate cell/column but cannot be clicked directly (not showing as hyperlink) and needs one or two two additional returns(enter) to make it appear as hyperlink that can then be opened in a browser window by clicking. If I type a new link in excel it shows it as hyperlink but not these imported hyperlinks.  Could be excel related issue. Also I want to post my revised code here. Not sure where to do so. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok you meant not a clickable link in excel. You said not a clickable link in pdf, so I was confused. That's a quick fix. just need to add the `=HYPERLINK("url")` function.

Comment: The code was updated with the hyperlink. Please accept the solution.

Comment: Code given by you is working fine. Solution fully Accepted.  Problem stands resolved fully

Comment: Do I have to tell somewhere on the site that this solution has been accepted.

Comment: No. If you look next to the solutions, by the upvote/downvote arrows, there should be a check mark. You just need to click on the Che I mark next to the solution you accept/like best.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of more information about your usecase would have helped to answer your question. However to extract the information about the *total number of pages* within the [website](https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/ann.html) you can access the site, click on the item with text as **Next** and extract the required data and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  # options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/ann.html")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Disclaimer']//following::div[1]//li[@class='pagination-last ng-scope']/a[@class='ng-binding' and text()='Last']"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Disclaimer']//following::div[1]//li[@class='pagination-page ng-scope active']/a[@class='ng-binding']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  17
  ```

Comment: Thanks will try it & revert back

Comment: @Ravi Let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: Tried this code.   
NameError: name 'WebDriverWait' is not defined

Comment: Did you `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`?

Comment: added that.  Now  
NameError: name 'EC' is not defined

Comment: Did you `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`

Comment: Just learning Python. May be not doing something that may be simple and needs to be done

Comment: No issues, each of the contributors on StackOverflow is not only helpful but friendly too. Good luck.

Comment: Seems Something more is to added  
NameError: name 'By' is not defined

Comment: Did you `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks. problem is resolved and accepted.

Comment: You helped me last  time with code for api for bse announcements, whereas i was trying tgo scrape the web page.  Is there any similar ape for nse too and if so the usgae for same in python please.